# Odoo version 13: Email digests & KPI's

Tags: hash, odoo, kpi

I am trying to create a new KPI in the Digests model to show the number of new customers created per week. (Unfortunately, this functionality is not well documented).
As documented, I have created two fields in the digest model:

x_studio_kpi_new_customers (Boolean)
x_studio_kpi_new_customers_value (Integer)

The value is

```
for record in self: 
    start, end, company = record._get_kpi_compute_parameters()
    record.x_studio_kpi_new_customers_value = sum(self.env['res.partner'].search([
            ('x_studio_when', '>=', start), 
            ('x_studio_when', '<', end)
    ]).mapped('x_studio_counter'))
```

x_studio_counter is just the value 1 in all records
x_studio_when is the record creation date (have also tried with a datetime field)

I have also tried the code below:

```
for record in self:
    start, end, company = record._get_kpi_compute_parameters()
    new_customers = self.env['res.partner'].search_count([('x_studio_when', '>=', start), ('x_studio_when', '<', end)])
    record['x_studio_kpi_new_customers_value'] = new_customers
```

I keep getting 0.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to build your customized digest, follow these steps:

1. You may want to add new computed fields with Odoo Studio:

   You must create 2 fields on the digest object:

   - first create a boolean field called kpi_myfield and display it in the KPI's tab;
   - then create a computed field called kpi_myfield_value that will compute your customized KPI.

Create below "compute_kpis_actions" method and after that digest mail able to view count.

```
def compute_kpis_actions(self, company, user):
        res = super(Digest, self).compute_kpis_actions(company, user)
        res['x_studio_kpi_new_customers'] = 'your_module_name.your_action_name&menu_id=%s' % self.env.ref(your_module_name.your_menu_name').id
        return res
```